# Magento - Product Page - Load image in main area

Tags: magento

In product page, I have one main image and 4 other images coming as thumbnail. I have coded now so that if any of 4 image is clicked, it will be loaded in main image area.

Now the issue comes of size. If I put via resize, each image is resized. If I don't call resize(), then it will show original size without zoom in case of big image.

Can I have something where I find the width and height of thumb nail image too. Based on this, I can code in media.phtml to call Resize() or not.

Can anyone help please?

Jeff

Comment: The default zoom tool is passable but not that fantastic from a user point of view. You may want to consider other tools such as 'MagicZoom' (costs money) or DeepZoom (free on connect). Choice depends on budget, whether you have high resolution images and how much time your site visitors spend on the product page.